# How to punch to target with animation rigging?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my character punch different targets in my scene. I'm using one of the [punch animations](https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&query=punch) from Mixamo. How can I make the character punch to target while playing the animation? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit uncertain as to what you are asking, but I assume it is this:

You have multiple animations, and when you press the punch button you want the punch animation to play regardless of any other animation.

If that is indeed what you are asking, and please correct me if I am wrong, you have to use **Animation Blend Trees** to mix animations.

---

### EDIT

So after reading the additional comments I can explain to you how to do that. And the answer does stay the same - **Animaiton Blend Trees**. Let me explain.

You will have two animations for each arm/hand. One that punches straight forward and another one that punches directly to the side.

A blend tree is essentially a blend between two animations to a various degree. In this case it will be a physical degree of 90. So say the enemy is diagonally (45 degrees) to the players left then you will need to calculate the angle and pass it to the blend tree which will mix the two animations to get you something in the middle.

So what you need to do is:

1. Get two animations where one is punching
2. Setup a blend tree for the two animations
3. When punching calculate the angle between what you are facing and where the enemy is. like this:

   ```
    public float max = 90;

    float GetBlendTreeInput() 
    {
        Vector3 forward = new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0, transform.forward.z);
        Vector3 enemyDirection = enemyTransform.position - transform.position;

        enemyDirection = new Vector3(enemyDirection.x, 0, enemyDirection.y);

        float angle = Vector3.Angle(forward, enemyDirection);
        float clampedAngle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, 0, max);

        return clampedAngle / max;
   }
   ```
4. Pass it to an animation variable that the blend tree observes.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. What I'm asking is - when I press the punch button, I need the character aim it's punch to the target. Now, the targets are not stationary, so the character needs to be able to throw/aim the punch in different directions. As I understand this can be done with animation rigging, but I'm not sure exactly how

Comment: I've set up the 2 bone IK constraint on the character's arm, so that the IK Constraint's source object target is an empty object ("hand target") aligned with the character's hand, essentially allowing to move the arm by moving the "hand target".

As I understand, I need to somehow move the "hand target" to my actual punch target when throwing the punch/playing punch animation. Any ideas on how to do this?